# SSIS - Validation phase is taking too long

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have an XML file and based on it I am looking to insert some information into my database. But first I need to split each node from the XML, to a source destination in SSIS. So far so good.

When I tried to execute the steps to see if I haven't missed something, I noticed that the `XML Source` step is taking too long, way too long, for at least 20 minutes before asking for help here. And each time I execute the package, a command prompt window pops up and quickly disappears.

I added some print screen below:

**Package quick review:**

[image]

**Data flow task review:**

[image]

**Progress review**

[image]

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before with an export column transform. It may be a visual studio issue. Try "Start without Debugging" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), if it works fine there then it'll work once deployed.